How to continue loop execution when error is caught
<cfloop from="2" to="#ArrayLen(MyList)#" index="i">
  ---Line of code---
  <cftry>
    ---Line of code----
    <cfcatch type="any">
      <cffile action = "append" file="#TempDirectory#\ErrorFile.csv" Output="#Mylist[i]#" addnewline="yes">
    </cfcatch>
  </cftry>
</cfloop>

Once the error is found within the try, the catch block will store the data in a file for which data the error occurred, But the cfloop will stop the execution, The Catch will not continue the cfloop execution.
Is there any other solution to store  the data in a file when the error occurs and continue the loop execution?

Once the error is caught, it should continue; it may help to know what the error actually is.

As long as the error is not a timeout, the loop should continue to execute.

Adding a cfdump to the cfcatch block might provide some useful information,

As far as I know, cfcatch itself doesn't interrupt the loop execution, but you can try moving the file writing outside cfcatch, and within cfcatch, just insert the data causing the error, for example, into a variable called 'errorData'. You can try adding this code after cftry:
<cfif StructKeyExists(cfcatch, "type")>
<cffile action="append" file="#TempDirectory#\ErrorFile.csv" output="#errorData#" addnewline="yes">

Also, you can try adding cfcontinue, but to reiterate, cfcatch shouldn't interrupt the loop execution

By reviewing you code its obvious that cfcatch should not interrupt the loop. But if its happening for you then it means you may have an error in catch block itself while writing in a file.
Anyway, the following is a sample code that demonstrate that as myvar is not defined so it will fall under catch block, however, you can see that its executing the loop without any interruption.
 <cfloop from="2" to="10" index="i">
  ---Line of code---<cfoutput>#i#</cfoutput><br>
  <cftry>
    ---Line of code----<cfoutput>#myvar#</cfoutput>
    <cfcatch type="any">
    <cfoutput> in catch #i#</cfoutput><br>
     <!--- <cffile action = "append" file="#TempDirectory#\ErrorFile.csv" Output="#Mylist[i]#" addnewline="yes"> --->
    </cfcatch>
  </cftry>
</cfloop>

